# Recursive time series forecasting test set

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, forecasting, train-test-split, recursive-model

Problem: I am building a multivariate model for recursive time series forecasting, where the goal is to make a 4-step-ahead forecast. The actual data for the forecasting period is available.
As far as I understand the forecast from each successive step is fed back into the model to generate the next step.
Consequently, adding this variable to the model would also imply that I must add it to the test set.

Ask: What should I add to the test set since the actual forecast values are only available after the forecast itself? Or am I barking up the wrong tree here?

Comment: Why you need to add your forecasted value to the test set while not do the same to the training set? Generally you don't mess with your test set, you just follow the same recursive forecast steps during training.

Comment: I do add the forecasted value to the training set.
I am working with R, to be more precise with the function predict, where I can forecast the next value but have to provide the test set. Since my model now has an additional variable, namely the forecasted value(s), I also have to provide values for this new variable in the test set.